# Real part of this complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm confused as to how to approach this problem. We are learning about the real and imaginary parts of a complex number.

$z=x+iy$
$$
\operatorname{Re} [(2+i)z]
$$

I multiplied out $2+i$ with $x+iy$ and then took the real parts to get $2x-y$. But it doesn't feel like it's right. That seems too simple.

---

**UPDATE**

Ok so the resounding response seems to be that I did it right. *However* how do you all explain [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexNumber.html) website? It defines $\operatorname{Re} z$ and $\operatorname{Im} z$ a bit differently.

> The real and imaginary parts are given by:

$$
\operatorname{Re} z = \frac {z + \bar z} 2 \\
\operatorname{Im} z = \frac {z - \bar z} {2i}
$$

Comment: What you did is correct, instead.

Comment: Complex numbers are simple.

Comment: @Did They are simple and yet complex.

Comment: Why did you expect it to be difficult?  Okay, this is usually a bad idea but let's look as how a ... less adequate... student could have gone wrong.  "(2 + i)z; the 2 is real and the i is not so the answer is 2z" or "(2 + i)(x + iy) = 2x + ix + 2iy - y so there are two real parts 2x and -y and I don't know which one they want" or "the x was the real part and 2x is the only x without an i so 2x is the real part".  They aren't asking for depth; just comprehension.  Which you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address your update: what you saw on MathWorld is correct: if $z = a + b {\rm i}$, then $\bar z = a - b {\rm i}$, so $$\frac {z + \bar z} 2 = \frac {a + b {\rm i} + a - b {\rm i}} 2 = a = \operatorname{Re} z ,$$ so there is no contradiction. A similar calculation can be done for $\operatorname{Im} z$.

Comment: Omg....thank you.....I can't believe I didn't notice that. You rock. Don't ever change.

Answer (score 0):

You're totally right!

Because:

$$\Re\left((2+i)(x+iy)\right)=\Re\left(2x+2iy+ix+iiy\right)=$$
$$\Re\left(2x+2iy+ix+i^2y\right)=\Re\left(2x+2iy+ix-y\right)=$$
$$\Re\left(2x-y+2iy+ix\right)=\Re\left((2x-y)+(2y+x)i\right)=2x-y$$

And, so:

$$\Im\left((2+i)(x+iy)\right)=2y+x$$

Comment: $(2y+x)i$ would be correct, no? For the imaginary part. You seem to have left out the $i$.

Comment: No, the $\Im(z)$ means the part with the $i$ part so you've to leave the $i$ out

Comment: Oh ok, thanks!!